# Specifying the distribution section outside the pom.xml

Tags: maven-2, artifactory

Is there a way I can specify the distribution managment section outside of the pom for a given project, but still only in the scope of that project?

I have a project that I'm forking from github and I would like to publish SNAPSHOT builds of that project to my internal Artifactory in the ext-snapshot-local repo. Ideally, I would like to point `mvn deploy` at my local repository without changing the pom and having to deal with constantly merging-in changes to the pom.

Comment: Run `mvn deploy-file` directly from command line. See [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to use the [Artifactory Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin) for this task. I was hoping to be able to do it locally, but having a CI server makes more sense. [This stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14887536/re-deployment-of-builds-from-artifactory-generic) gave me the idea.